# List of namespaces in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

How do I get a list of security namespaces and their Id's in Visual Studio Team Services? I am trying to access the namespaces to set permissions. The hyperlink on the api reference website returns http code 404

Comment: Do you mean namespaces in your code? Or for their APIs?

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: I mean namepaces in the REST API of VSTS. The answer of Daniel helped me out. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 9):

I just dealt with this a few days ago (including the annoying realization that the link is dead).

You have to GET the `securitynamespaces` API with an empty guid:

`GET http://my-vsts-account.visualstudio.com/_apis/securitynamespaces/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`

Comment: Thank you Daniel, your answer gave me a List of namespaces in VSTS where I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

The most up to date namespaces, snippets, and docs that I've seen are available on the [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-dotnet-samples/tree/c1caebb2c87c5fc09254a2c58f0a6a7d49b2d719).

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Security namespaces are a specific subset of the REST APIs. They're also a big pain to work with.

Comment: Really dude? So code examples with the security namespaces on that github aren't useful? Give me a break: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-dotnet-samples/blob/2790700757af8d78c6d8269f4c50799d58ddde55/ClientLibrary/Snippets/Microsoft.TeamServices.Samples.Client/Security/SecurityNamespacesSample.cs

Comment: The example uses REST API too.